# Use function for value input in html with ajax, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I have an ajax function that is actually working well but I don't know how to use it on the HTML.
What I need to achieve is that basically, attached to each checkbox there is a certain number of questions. They're all selected by default but, if I deselect one of them, the number of questions of that particular checkbox should be removed.
The function I am using is working fine (in the console) but I couldn't find a way to use it on the HTML.
I post some code for more clarity.

```js
let subjectId;
      $("#selection").on("change", function () {
        const selectSubjBtn = document.getElementById("select_subject");
        subjectId = $(this).children(":selected").val();
        let labelText = gettext(
          "Select the number of questions by moving the button to the right or left!"
        );
        let title = gettext("Select Number of Questions");
        let selectedQuestionsNum;
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/quiz/ajax_questions/" + subjectId,
          success: function (response) {
            let questions = response.questions;
            let topics = response.topics;
            let topicQuestionNum = response.question_num_list;
            if (topicQuestionNum != 0) {
              let topicsObj = topics.map(function (e, i) {
                return [e, topicQuestionNum[i]];
              });
              let subTopicHtml;
              // $("#sub_topic_box").append(
              //   '<input class="form-check-input mt-0 ms-3" type="checkbox" value="" id="selectAll" checked aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">'
              // );
              topicsObj.forEach((el) => {
                subTopicHtml = '<div class="row mt-3">';
                subTopicHtml += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
                subTopicHtml += '<div class="input-group-text">';
                subTopicHtml +=
                  '<input class="form-check-input selectedTopic mt-0" type="checkbox" value="' +
                  el[1] +
                  '" id="' +
                  el[0].id +
                  '" checked aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">';
                subTopicHtml += "</div>";
                subTopicHtml +=
                  '<input value="' +
                  el[0].name +
                  '" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with checkbox" disabled>';
                subTopicHtml +=
                  '<span class="input-group-text">' + el[1] + "</span>";
                subTopicHtml += "</div></div>";
                $("#sub_topic_box").append(subTopicHtml);
              });
              $("#selectAll").click(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                  $(":checkbox").each(function () {
                    this.checked = true;
                  });
                } else {
                  $(":checkbox").each(function () {
                    this.checked = false;
                  });
                }
              });
              let selectedQuestionTopic =
                document.getElementsByClassName("selectedTopic");
              let selectedCheckboxes = [];
              let selectedBoxesNum;
              function selectedTopics() {
                selectedCheckboxes = [];
                let checked = document.querySelectorAll(
                  "[type='checkbox']:checked"
                );
                checked.forEach(function (el) {
                  selectedCheckboxes.push(Number(el.value));
                  selectedBoxesNum = selectedCheckboxes.reduce(
                    (pv, cv) => pv + cv,
                    0
                  );
                });
                console.log(selectedBoxesNum);
                return selectedBoxesNum;
              }
    
              selectedQuestionTopic.forEach(function (el) {
                el.addEventListener("change", function () {
                  selectedTopics();
                });
              });
    
              quizBox.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="h5 mb-3">${title}</div>
                    <div class="row mt-3">
                    <label for="customRange1" class="form-label">${labelText}</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textInput" value="${selectedQuestionsNum}" oninput="${selectedQuestionsNum};" >
                              <span class="input-group-text">on ${
                                questions.length
                              }</span>
              <input type="range" name="question_number" class="form-range mt-3" min="0" max="${
                questions.length
              }" value="${
                questions.length
              }" id="customRange1" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);"
              oninput="updateTextInput(this.value);">
                <div class="mt-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="select_subject">${gettext(
                      "Select Subject"
                    )}</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                `;
            } else {
              quizBox.innerHTML = `
                  <div class="h5 mb-3">${title}</div>
                  <div class="row mt-3">
                  <label for="customRange1" class="form-label">${labelText}</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textInput" value="${
                              questions.length
                            }" oninput="customRange1.value=amount.value" >
                            <span class="input-group-text">on ${
                              questions.length
                            }</span>
            <input type="range" name="question_number" class="form-range mt-3" min="0" max="${
              questions.length
            }" value="${
                questions.length
              }" id="customRange1" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);"
            oninput="updateTextInput(this.value);">
              <div class="mt-3">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="select_subject">${gettext(
                    "Select Subject"
                  )}</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              `;
            }
          },
          error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          },
        });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Basically, `topicQuestionNum` variable is an array, which I sum in the `selectedTopics` function and, in case I uncheck one of the checkboxes, it gives me a new result.
What I need to do, is updating also the result in the input field I create with the ajax request down below.
I tried in many different ways but I don't have much experience, especially with Javascript.